# My ajax call is working only once but its not working again unless i refresh the page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make a form executed using Ajax. Here is my html part where i am trying to enter

```
 <form class="col s12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s6">
                <i class="material-icons prefix">mode_edit</i>
                <textarea id="icon_prefix2" class="materialize-textarea" name ="discussion"></textarea>
                <input type="hidden" name="user" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['userid'];?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo(rand(1000,99999)); ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="date" value="<?php echo date("d.m.Y"); ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="time" value="<?php echo date("h:i:s"); ?>">
                <label for="icon_prefix2">Start your discsussion</label>
                <input type="submit" class="btn waves-effect waves-light right" value="post">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

and the ajax call is

```
$(function () {

    $('form').on('submit', function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'cardiosubmit.php',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function () {
                alert('successfully posted')
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('error')
            }

        });

    });

});
```

and this is the php code to store the values in DB:

```
<?php

session_start();


include_once('include/config.php');

$conn = config();

$uname = $_POST['user'];
$uid = $_POST['id'];
$val = $_POST['discussion'];
$date = $_POST['date'];`enter code here`
$time = $_POST['time'];

if (!$conn) {
$msg = "connection failed";
die($msg);
} else {
$query = "INSERT into cardiocase (id,uid,val,date,time) VALUES 
(?,?,?,?,?);";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('sssss',$uid,$uname,$val,$date,$time);

if($stmt->execute()){
    echo "success";
}else{
    echo "fail";
}
$stmt->close();

}
```

the value gets stored for the first time. but after the success message when i try to enter again it just says successfully posted, but when i check the DB the values are not there. if i refresh the page and try again its getting stored.

Comment: is `iud` field unique in `cardiocase` DB ? I guess you might be interested in getting a response from PHP : add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1);` on top of your page, and, in JS, use the PHP echo -> `success: function (data) { alert(data)}` + `error: function (request, status, error) {  alert(request.responseText); }`

Comment: the 'uid' ('id' in table) is the primary key

Comment: well, `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo(rand(1000,99999)); ?>">` remains the same after Ajax call...

Comment: your hidden input are useless here, generate those values directly in the php file

Comment: ya got it thanx :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

improve your code like that :

```
<form class="col s12">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s6">
            <i class="material-icons prefix">mode_edit</i>
            <textarea id="icon_prefix2" class="materialize-textarea" name ="discussion"></textarea>
            <label for="icon_prefix2">Start your discsussion</label>
            <input type="submit" class="btn waves-effect waves-light right" value="post">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Remove hidden fields

Then in the php file :

```
 <?php
session_start();


include_once('include/config.php');

$conn = config();

$uname = $_SESSION['userid'];
$uid = echo(rand(1000,99999));;
$val = $_POST['discussion'];
$date = date("d.m.Y");
$time = date("h:i:s");

if (!$conn) {
$msg = "connection failed";
die($msg);
} else {
$query = "INSERT into cardiocase (id,uid,val,date,time) VALUES 
(?,?,?,?,?);";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('sssss',$uid,$uname,$val,$date,$time);

if($stmt->execute()){
    echo "success";
}else{
    echo "fail";
}
$stmt->close();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with this line

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo(rand(1000,99999)); ?>">
```

First time you make ajax call new row will be inserted to table with say id "123" now while making next ajax call your id is still same, and your are trying to add new row to table with duplicate primary key.

Try to generated new id (may be through javascript) every time before making ajax call.

```
$(function () {

    $('form').on('submit', function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        //Generate random id for very ajax request.
        $("[name='id']").val(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100));

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'cardiosubmit.php',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function () {
                alert('successfully posted')
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('error')
            }

        });

    });

});
```

Comment: or simply generate the id in the php file. this field is useless here

Comment: agree, you can have auto increment id for table in database

Answer (score 0):

Use preventDefault() to avoid form submission.

```
$('body').on("click", '.btn', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent default functionality
        // run AJAX

 });
```

It looks like there's an error with JS somewhere
use to see what is AJAX result

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'cardiosubmit.php',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function () {
                alert('successfully posted')
            },
            complete: function (data, textStatus) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                console.log(textStatus);
            }
        });
```

Comment: actually i want to submit the form. whats the use in avoiding form submission. and yet i tried this. but still the same issue

Comment: $('form').serialize() already emulates form submission you don't need to submit the form, just run it on click event instead. Edited my answer to debug the problem better look what is coming back from server

Answer (score 0):

use following code 
change ur button in HTML `<button class="btn waves-effect waves-light right trigger-submit" value="post">POST</button>`

update js code with this

`$(".trigger-submit").off("click");
 $(".trigger-submit").on("click", function () {
   $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'cardiosubmit.php',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function () {
                alert('successfully posted')
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('error')
            }

```
    });
```

});`

Answer (score 0):

```
   <form action="cardiosubmit.php" class="col s12" id="myfrm" method="post" name="myfrm" >     
<div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s6">
        <i class="material-icons prefix">mode_edit</i>
        <textarea id="icon_prefix2" class="materialize-textarea" name ="discussion"></textarea>
        <label for="icon_prefix2">Start your discsussion</label>
        <input type="submit" class="btn waves-effect waves-light right" value="post">
    </div>
</div>   
</form>
 <script type="text/javascript">   
 var frm = $('#myfrm');   

frm.submit(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: frm.attr('method'),
        url: frm.attr('action'),
        data: frm.serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('Submission was successful.');
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log('An error occurred.');
            console.log(data);
        },
    });
});
```

try this!!!